# Vue pass hidden input to axios

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I want to pass the following hidden input to laravel using axios. I'm aware that V-model does not work with hidden inputs

```
<form @submit.prevent="acceptBudget" >
    <input type="hidden" name="contractor_user_id" :value="contractor.user_id">
    <input type="text"  v-model="budget_form.budget">
    <button>Accept budget</button>
</form>
```

This is my Vue data property

```
data() {
    return {
        budget_form: {
            accept_budget: '1',
            budget: '',
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my method that posts the data

```
methods: {
    async acceptBudget () {
        await axios.post('/api/maintenances/respond/budget', this.budget_form)
    }
}
```

How do I pass the hidden input through axios?

Comment: `contractor.user_id` from  where this value coming from?? is this in a loop??

Comment: yes, it's in a v-for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel vue getting info by hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788294/laravel-vue-getting-info-by-hidden-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there's no loop you can simply set the hidden input value in vue end. but as you are saying the value is coming from a loop, a possible solution would be passing the hidden input value with the form submit.

```
<form @submit.prevent="acceptBudget(contractor.user_id)" >
    <input type="text" v-model="budget_form.budget">
    <button>Accept budget</button>
</form>
```

and then in method update form with that value

```
methods: {
    async acceptBudget(user_id) {
        this.budget_form.user_id = user_id;
        await axios.post('/api/maintenances/respond/budget', this.budget_form)
    }
}
```

and your form object is

```
budget_form: {
    accept_budget: '1',
    budget: '',
    user_id: ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that v-model doesn't work with hidden inputs. In this case, I would prefer to add a data attribute to the button and read it in the method. Since you want to pass one data, I think this can be the easiest way.

```
<button :data-user="contractor.user_id">Accept budget</button>
```

```
async acceptBudget (event) {
  this.budget_form.user_id = event.target.querySelector("button").dataset.user;
  await axios.post('/api/maintenances/respond/budget', this.budget_form)

}
```